# Find object by tag

Tags: ios, tags, nsobject

I have `UITableView` with `UITextField`s inside cells. Every `UITextField` has his own tag. How to access `UITextField` by tag? I was trying to google that answer, but looks like first 5 pages shows how to check tag of sender.

Comment: Is there multiple UITextFields inside each cell? Or are you referring to the UITableView as a whole with each cell having one UITextField?  If it's the latter, I ask then why you would need to access each UITextField by tag?

Comment: Each cell contains one UITextLable. I just created pointers in @interface, so problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Create pointers in @interface, and do:

```
self.carBody = cellTextField;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the reference using **viewWithTag**
and send message to the reference as you do normally.

```
UITextField *tfObj=(UITextField*)[tblVuObj viewWithTag:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

A UITableView only holds visible cells. Therefor, you cannot access cells that are not visible. To iterate through visible cells:

for ( UITableViewCell *aCell in [theTable visibleCells] )
{
  UITextField *aField = (UITextField *)[aCell viewWithTag:kYourTextFieldTag];
}