# Find object by tag (in swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, tags, uiimage

I have a variable `@IBOutlet var ImageViews: [UIImageView]!` that holds my 36 UIImages from the storyboard. I have set a tag to one random Image;

```
ImageViews[5].tag = 5
```

I want to be able to find this Image through the tag only and change its background color.

(Image in ImageViews with tag 5)

[HERE'S THE CODE IN C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281788/find-object-by-tag)  maybe you can translate it? I can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let imageView = ImageViews.filter { $0.tag == 5 }.first
imageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: How do I use this to apply a background color? Do i do `imageView[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
extension UIView {
    func findSubview(withTag tag: Int) -> UIView? {
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if subview.tag == tag {
                return subview
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

It would be used like this:

```
imageView.findSubview(withTag: 5)!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Array where Element: UIView {
    func viewWithTag(tag: Int) -> UIView? {
        return filter { $0.tag == tag }.first
    }
}
```

`let subview = ImageViews.viewWithTag(5)`

Note: Use camel case for classes, methods, variables, etc.
https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide